# Query to get distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

table - order

columnA   1    1    2    3    4    4    5

columnB   80  20   80    80   80   20   80

columnA having columnB = 20 should not be retrieved, need the result as below.

columnA   2    3    5

columnB   80  80  80

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ yourself? "Here, I'm too lazy to figure this out so do it for me for free"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select * from `order` where c1 not in (select c1 from `order` where c2 = 20)
 group by c1
```

**NOTE : that `order` is mysql reserved keyword , so you should escape it by backticks

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4705a/1)

```
C1  C2
2   80
3   80
5   80
```

Comment: make sure used the updated answer. and take a look to demo also

Comment: the query is good and result are right it must be something wrong you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Try NOT IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE C1 NOT IN (SELECT C1
                 FROM table
                 WHERE c2 = 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.c1, o.c2
FROM `order` o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM `order` o2
    WHERE o.c1 = o2.c1
      AND o2.c2 = 20
)
;
```

Comment: Rathna, my query take care of thing the other two does not so far and the way it is written, it speaks the intention (e.g., WHERE NOT EXISTS).  And please don't forget to up-vote and accept my answer, I am a new user so I guess this is important else I cannot do certain action.